# React Native - NavigatorIOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

i would like to ask why the backgroundcolor of NavigatorIOS is much lighter than the usual color. The actual color of the header should be the same on the text below (actual color).

Here's the code:

```
<NavigatorIOS
            itemWrapperStyle={styles.navWrap}
            style={styles.nav}
            barTintColor="#9b2b25"
            initialRoute={{
                title: "Login",
                component: Login
            }} />
```

The Stylesheet

```
navWrap: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 70
},
nav: {
    flex: 1
}
```

here's the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NavigatorIOS is **translucent by [default](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Navigation/NavigatorIOS.ios.js#L619)**. Propably you can notice that, by pushing your text up, behind the navigationbar.

Set *[translucent](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html#Props)* to false should disable that behaviour:

```
<NavigatorIOS
        itemWrapperStyle={styles.navWrap}
        style={styles.nav}
        barTintColor="#9b2b25"
        translucent={false}
        initialRoute={{
            title: "Login",
            component: Login
        }} />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You save my day!